# How to use/open psql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, psql

I have installed On windows 7  postgreSQL 9.2 version.

Now, I need use psql, so where is this terminal?

Can you tell me please how to use for example this comand: `psql databasename` ?

Where must be type this?

Yes, may be  this is dumb question, but...

Comment: You do know how to open a commandline (cmd.exe) window? "Start -> Run -> cmd.exe" then type `psql databasename`

Answer (score 6):

You can follow this instruction

1. Open the command prompt
2. cd C:\postgresql-9.3.0-1-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\bin (installed directory)
3. Run: initdb -U postgres -A password -E utf8 -W -D POSTGRESQL_ROOT\data
4. give super user password (Remember that)
5. you wiil get the success message

Success. You can now start the database server using:

```
"postgres" -D "POSTGRESQL_ROOT\data"
```

or
    "pg_ctl" -D "POSTGRESQL_ROOT\data" -l logfile start

then, you are good to start the server

To stop the server : simply ctrl + c

You can use pgAdmin tool(http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.8.4/win32/) somewhat similar like SQL Mgt Studio

Reference : http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/installing-postgresql-9-1-to-windows-7-from-the-binary-zip-distribution/

Comment: No need to reinstall, i have updated the steps, you can follow that. psql is in Mac, for Windows its pgsql

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to start is

1. Open Run Window by Winkey + R
2. Type services.msc
3. Search Postgres service based on version installed.
4. Click stop, start or restart the service option.